Calculating the weights of error mechanisms in stim
Suppose we have a very simple stim circuit
circuit = stim.Circuit('''
    X_ERROR(0.125) 0
    X_ERROR(0.25) 1
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.6) 0 1
    M 0 1
    DETECTOR rec[-2]
    DETECTOR rec[-1]
''')

And we can see that four possible errors will cause the joint flip of D0 and D1 detectors, as shown in the explain_detecor_error_model_errors module:
ExplainedError {
    dem_error_terms: D0 D1
    CircuitErrorLocation {
        flipped_pauli_product: X0*X1
        Circuit location stack trace:
            (after 0 TICKs)
            at instruction #3 (DEPOLARIZE2) in the circuit
            at targets #1 to #2 of the instruction
            resolving to DEPOLARIZE2(0.6) 0 1
    }
    CircuitErrorLocation {
        flipped_pauli_product: X0*Y1
        Circuit location stack trace:
            (after 0 TICKs)
            at instruction #3 (DEPOLARIZE2) in the circuit
            at targets #1 to #2 of the instruction
            resolving to DEPOLARIZE2(0.6) 0 1
    }
    CircuitErrorLocation {
        flipped_pauli_product: Y0*X1
        Circuit location stack trace:
            (after 0 TICKs)
            at instruction #3 (DEPOLARIZE2) in the circuit
            at targets #1 to #2 of the instruction
            resolving to DEPOLARIZE2(0.6) 0 1
    }
    CircuitErrorLocation {
        flipped_pauli_product: Y0*Y1
        Circuit location stack trace:
            (after 0 TICKs)
            at instruction #3 (DEPOLARIZE2) in the circuit
            at targets #1 to #2 of the instruction
            resolving to DEPOLARIZE2(0.6) 0 1
    }
}

In the meantime, the weights of error mechanisms indicate by running print(circuit.detector_error_model())
error(0.275) D0
error(0.2) D0 D1
error(0.35) D1

I am wondering why the weight of D0 D1 is 0.2, other than 0.6/15*4 since the only error location that could possibly cause the joint flip of D0 and D1 will be DEPOLARIZE2(0.6) 0 1, and 4/15 of the possible error configurations will trigger the detector flip.

The key thing to realize is that the 15 cases within DEPOLARIZE2 are disjoint whereas the error mechanisms in a detector error model are independent. So they can't just be linear rescalings of each other.
For example, suppose you deleted the X errors that are confusing the issue a bit, leaving only the DEPOLARIZE2(0.1) error. Then suppose you manually converted that into the dem
error(0.08) D0
error(0.16) D1
error(0.08) D0 D1

by just dividing 0.1 by 15 and counting up cases. This dem is wrong! If you sample from it, you'll find it gives different detection event statistics than sampling the circuit! For example, you would see detector 1 firing by itself 7.36% of the time instead of 8% of the time. Because in order to end up with just D1, the D1 error has to happen without the D0 or D0 D1 errors also happening (alternatively, D1 can not happen while both D0 and D0 D1 happen). So the net probability of getting a result of D1 from this dem is P(D1)*P(not D0)*P(not D0 D1) + P(D1)*P(not D0)*P(not D0 D1) = 0.0736 instead of the correct 0.08.
To fix this, you need to convert from disjoint probabilities to independent probabilities. For two qubit depolarization the independent probability $p$ relates to the disjoint probability $d$ like this:
$$p = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 - \frac{16}{15}d \right)^{1/8}$$
A secondary thing is that, if an independent error appears twice, like error(p) D1 and also error(q) D1, combining them into one case requires combining their independent probabilities into a single independent probability using Bernoulli addition instead of normal addition:
$$\text{combined}(p, q) = p(1-q) + q(1-p)$$
That said... all this stuff is only really noticeable when you're using enormous probabilities like 0.6. The correct thing converges to "just rescale and add" as probabilities go down. For a more typical noise strength, like 0.001, you can get away with those simplifications. But I know how much people like simulating their code capacity constructions near thresholds of 10% or whatever, and there this kind of detail can really matter. Although... details like errors being coherent during rounds probably also starts to matter...
