detector_error_model with stim
The following code is a simple repetition code (for two qubits and one ancilla) for detecting Z errors:
eps = 0.1

circuit = stim.Circuit()
circuit.append("RX", [0,1,2])

circuit.append("DEPOLARIZE2", [0,2], eps)
circuit.append("CNOT", [2,0])
circuit.append("CNOT", [2,1])

circuit.append("MRX", [2])
circuit.append("DETECTOR", [stim.target_rec(-1)])


circuit.append("CNOT", [2,0])
circuit.append("CNOT", [2,1])

circuit.append("MRX", [2])
circuit.append("DETECTOR", [stim.target_rec(-2),stim.target_rec(-1)])


Errors on detections are different from the ones I expect to get from a transferring depolarzing2 to z2_error model [e---->(12/15 * e)]. In other words, I would expect to get error 4*e/15 for each detection D0, D1, and {D0D1}. I am wondering what I am missing.

Does this answer your question? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/38535/calculating-the-weights-of-error-mechanisms-in-stim/38537#38537

Yes, that is exactly what I was asking for. I now understand general prospects, but in that example (when removing X error, only having depolarizing ones) I expect D0 D1 to be the same as depolarizing channel is symmetric. but you put different errors for them: error(0.08) D0 error(0.16) D1. So now I am confused about that.

probably just a typo

Ah, ok. Thanks again for the clarification.
